# using if with Today() and cutom date cells usually return True?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I received excel sheet with dates in column U as (Jul 8, 2009).

I changed cells format to custom date (mmm d, yyyy)

now in column V, I added below if statement

```
=IF(U9="";"No Date";IF(U9>TODAY();"warranty";"expired"))
```

my problem is: why all values returned as "warranty" what ever date in column U?

May 10, 2016.....warranty

Jul 8, 2011.........warranty

Jan 1, 2017........warranty

Jul 23, 2011........warranty

Comment: provide a link to the example worksheet

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on the automatic calculation:
**Options>Formulas>Workbook calculation>Automatic**

[image]

Or you can turn it on in the formulas tab in the tool bar:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data in the sheet might be wrong - have you checked its value and compared this to the value of today? (use the value function on the cell is probably easiest)

There is a '1904' date setting deep in the bowels of the options (under advanced) which some systems use - whereby the dates started at a different point that Excels usual. This means that today would not match today - and the situation you are describing is possible.

Comment: originally this option not checked, and still the same after checking it.

Comment: It was just a hunch - I had a similar problem caused by this. You have said above that by using value pointed to the cell - you get an error? This would explain the issue, as the dates are not as numbers. If you do 'Value(thecellinquestion)' - do you get a number?

Answer (score 0):

The dates you received might have been formatted as **Text**. In that case changing the cell format won't convert it to date, and some formulas and expressions will regard it as text and not as a date value.

To verify this try to change the date format on one of the date cells that calculate incorrectly to some other date format or number, and you will see there is no effect.

**One solution** is to add the `DATEVALUE()` function to your formula:

```
=IF(U9="";"No Date";IF(DATEVALUE(U9)>TODAY();"warranty";"expired"))
```

This will work only if all of your dates are formatted as text.

**Another solution** is to run **Text to Columns** from the Data menu. This process has the side-effect of converting data types.

1. Select your dates column and run Text to Columns.
2. Choose Delimited and click Next.
3. Remove any selected Delimiters and click Next.
4. You may choose General or Date and click Finish.

After that your original formula should work correctly.

### Addition:

It seems this is not a typical problem and it might have to do with the machine locale settings and date format recognition.

A possible workaround can be using this formula to retrieve the correct date value from a date text formatted as `MMM d, yyyy`:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(U9,4),
   MATCH(LEFT(U9,3),
     {"Jan","Feb","Mar","April","May","jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}
     ,0),
  NUMBERVALUE(MID(U9,5,2)))
```

For easy copy:

```
DATE(RIGHT(U9,4),MATCH(LEFT(U9,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","April","May","jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),NUMBERVALUE(MID(U9,5,2)))
```

Replace the `U9` part of your original formula with this formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but both solutions not working, use date value return value error #VALUE!, and text to column don't affect original formula result.

Comment: What happens when you change the number format of a date cell?

Comment: Does the cell value contain any other characters apart from `Jul 8, 2011`?

Comment: NO don't contain any other characters apart from Jul 8, 2011

Comment: I suspect some non-visible character is preset. What is the result of `=CODE(U9)`?

Comment: It might be a locale settings problem, and if so this date format is just not recognized by your system. If you enter this date to a new cell set to General number format does your formula work? What is your computer locale?